# Converting T-SQL to PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql

How can I convert the following T-SQL Statement to PL/SQL

```
set @disbursement_no = (select isnull(max(convert(numeric, right(DV_NO, 6))), 0) + 1
            from CD_T_DV_HDR where year(DATE_DV) = year(getdate()))
```

The data type of `DV_NO` is varchar and `Date_Dv` is date.

I'm really new to PL/SQL, and I'm having a hard time to convert my SQL statement to  PL/SQL. I Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be like this:

```
DECLARE
    disbursement_no NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT ( coalesce(MAX(To_number(Substr(dv_no, -6, 6))), 0) ) + 1
    INTO   disbursement_no
    FROM   cd_t_dv_hdr
    WHERE  To_char(date_dv, 'rrrr') = To_char(SYSDATE, 'rrrr');
END;
```

[`Substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions169.htm#SQLRF06114)`(dv_no, -6, 6)` fetches the rightmost 6 characters. [`to_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions199.htm#SQLRF06140) converts the string to number. [`max`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions090.htm#SQLRF00666) fetches maximum number & [`coalesce`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) checks if the resultant number is null & converts it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

One thing regarding @Sathya comment:
in case DATE_DV is indexed/used as a partitioned key column Oracle won't use the index/partition because you have a function on the column.
this will cause Full Table scan on the entire table which will be bad.

you have 2 options:
1. change the index/partition to use the function  -bad idea in 90% of the cases
2. Use between in you where condition

```
SELECT ( coalesce(MAX(To_number(Substr(dv_no, -6, 6))), 0) ) + 1
INTO   disbursement_no
FROM   cd_t_dv_hdr
WHERE  date_dv between trunc(sysdate,'rrrr') and trunc(add_months(sysdate,12),'rrrr')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE
  disbursement_no int;
BEGIN
  select (case when DV_NO is null 0 else max(to_number(right(DV_NO,6),'999999')) end)+1 into disbursement_no
    from CD_T_DV_HDR 
    where extract(year from DATE_DV)  = extract(year from current_date);
END;
```

I think that'll pretty much do it.  I'm sure there's other ways, there might be an equivalent of isnull() in postgresql, but I don't know it if there is.  Obviously you'll need the rest of the function, including some return etc.

It's also worth noting that the text type in PostgreSQL is much smarter than its equivalent in other systems, and varchar can usually be replaced by text unless there are particular considerations.

Also, if this is a frequent query, you can create an index on the where clause:

```
create index my_year_index on CD_T_DV_HDR (extract(year from DATE_DV));
```

This is one of the really nice features of PostgreSQL: creating indexes based on expressions.

Comment: Postgres? PL/SQL is Oracle's extensions - [Postgres' is PL/pgSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/pgSQL)